# Proof this form

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I am trying to proof this form:

Let $g(.)$ be a function, for $y_n$ is a a nonnegative random variable, $\varepsilon>0$, $g(x)>0$ is increasing function for $x>0$, and  $E[g(x)]>0$, then

Pr(|x| >\varepsilon)\leq E[g(x)]/g(\varepsilon)

Can I show this proof by using

E[g(x)]=Pr(|x| >\varepsilon)E[g(x)|g(x) > g(\varepsilon)]$$+Pr(g(x) \leq\varepsilon)E[g(x)|g(x)\leq g(\varepsilon)]

Comment: @Davide I revised it already to make it clear.

Comment: The random variable here is $x$, isn't it ?

Comment: @jibounet yes $x$ is random variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $g$ is increasing, we have 
$$\mathbb P\{X>\varepsilon\}\leqslant \mathbb P\{g(X)>g(\varepsilon)\}.$$
And now, it's a simple application of Markov's inequality $\mathbb P\{Y>a\}\leqslant \frac 1a\mathbb E[Y]$ where $Y$ is a non-negative random variable and $a$ a positive real number.

Comment: To understand the inequality: since $g$ is increasing, if $X>\epsilon$, by definition we have $g(X)>g(\epsilon)$. This means that $\{w\in\Omega : X(\omega)>\epsilon\} \subseteq \{w\in\Omega : g(X(\omega))>g(\epsilon)\}$. By monotonicity of the probability measure ($A\subset B \Rightarrow P(A)\leq P(B)$) you get $$P(X>\epsilon)\leq P(g(X)>g(\epsilon))$$

Comment: @DimaMcGreen many thanks for your explanation..really helpful.