# What is the meaning of $E[g(x)]=Pr(|x| >\varepsilon)E[g(x)|g(x) > g(\varepsilon)]+Pr(g(x) \leq\varepsilon)E[g(x)|g(x)\leq g(\varepsilon)]$

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory

Any body knows the meaning of this expectation ($E[g(x)]$) form?

$E[g(x)]=Pr(g(x) >\varepsilon)E[g(x)|g(x) > g(\varepsilon)]+Pr(g(x) \leq\varepsilon)E[g(x)|g(x)\leq g(\varepsilon)]$

Comment: Where did you come across this? Why is there a $|x|$ in there?

Comment: @TenaliRaman, yes it incorrect. any way I revised it already..

Comment: @Dima thanks for your advise, any way can you help me to interconnected this proof to my Markov Inequality? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/467255/markov-inequality-prx-varepsilon-leq-egx-g-varepsilon

Answer (score 1):

You can easily see that $1=1(g(x)>g(\epsilon)) + 1(g(x)\leq g(\epsilon))$. Using this you have
$$ E(g(x)\cdot 1) = E(g(x) 1(g(x)>\epsilon)) + E(g(x) 1(g(x)\leq \epsilon)) = \frac{P(g(x)>\epsilon)}{P(g(x)>\epsilon)}E(g(x) 1(g(x)>\epsilon)) + \frac{P(g(x)\leq\epsilon)}{P(g(x)\leq \epsilon)}E(g(x) 1(g(x)\leq \epsilon)) = P(g(x)>\epsilon) E(g(x) \,|\, g(x)> \epsilon) + P(g(x)\leq\epsilon) E(g(x) \,|\,g(x)\leq \epsilon) 
$$
by the definition of the conditional expectation, assuming that $P(g(x)\leq \epsilon)\in(0,1)$. This is sort of a case-by-case analysis, which is helpful in proofs. You might know something about $P^{g(x)}$ if $g$ is small, which you could make use of by considering the form above.

Comment: thanks for your advise, any way can you help me to interconnected this proof to my Markov Inequality? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/467255/markov-inequality-prx-varepsilon-leq-egx-g-varepsilon

Comment: There is an answer to that question, do you need help understanding it?

Comment: @Dima..yes please let me know. thanks

Comment: @alexa I added a comment to the answer

Answer (score 1):

This is an application of what is sometimes called the Law of Total Expectation: $EX=EE[X|Y]$.  In your case,  $X = g(x)$ and $Y = 1_{\{g(x)>\epsilon\}}$.

Really, we are applying the Law of the Unconscious Statistician as well:  In your case, since $Y$ is Bernoulli, $Eh(Y) = h(0)P\{Y=0\}+h(1)P\{Y=1\}$, where  $h(Y) = E[X|Y]$.

Comment: Sorry but this is much more elaborate than needed (try the simplest Bayes formula on a partition of size 2).

Comment: @Did:  What does Bayes' formula have to do wiht the expectation of a general random variable?

Comment: Bayes formula for a random variable $Z$ and a partition $\{A,A^c\}$ reads $E[Z]=P[A]E[Z\mid A]+P[A^c]E[Z\mid A^c]$.

Comment: I have never seen that referred to as Bayes' formula before.  Reference?  Bayes' formula is rather universally understood as a relationship between conditional probabilities (or occasionally densities).

Comment: See first page of [this](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~gravner/MAT135B/materials/ch11.pdf) (simply one of the first google hits, I am not related to the author). Anyway, even if you object to calling this B formula for expectations, nevertheless this is simpler stuff than what you invoke. No?

Comment: Does not come up so readily when I google "Bayes' formula."  It is highly nonstandard terminology.  Also, your citation refers to the more general formula first, then cites yours as a special case.

Comment: This is becoming unpleasant: google `bayes formula expectation`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10150/discussion-between-stephen-herschkorn-and-did)